# Disable cPanel from looking for user for Forward email

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

I have 2 domains setup on the same server using WHM. One is a full site, with cPanel email/Forwarding.  The other is redirects and using Google apps as the email.

When I setup a forward on the full site to the Google apps, it is searching cPanel for the user of the second domain and says the User doesn't exist, but it does exist on Google Apps.

How can I disable cPanel from checking for a specific user on the redirect domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can understand your problem. now make 2 changes on your cPanel account.

1. Remove its all existing MX records and use only Google app MX
2. cPanel => Mx Entry => Remote Mail Exchanger

Check below screenshot

[image]

I hope it will sure help you